# clearcase view is locked by another process, how could i break the lock from ccrc?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I tried to update a clear case view with CCRC tool. Sometimes the view will be locked if last update was aborted for some reason, and couldn't be updated before the lock is broke. Is there anyone could help to tell me how could I unlock this view with CCRC tool?

Here's the error message when i run command update in rcleartool.

> CRMAP7009: CCRC command "Update" failed: Error:
>   "com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.copyarea.CopyAreaLockedException:
>   Copy area "/Users/vizmacmini2/Jenkins/jenBranch941u1_vizmacmini2" is
>   locked by another process.  Retry the request once that operation
>   completes. Lock info: last-refreshed:Nov 14, 2013 5:38:02 PM
>   locked-on:Nov 14, 2013 4:41:07 PM user-id:vizmacmini2
>   hostname:10.197.40.115 process-id:unknown." conflict

Comment: What version of CCRC are you using? Do you have a screenshot of the error message you see, illustrating that "locked" status of your view?

Comment: @VonC thanks for your help! My version is CCRC CLI version 8.0.0.0. I have edited the question to add error message. And I could update the view from UI client as it will pop-up a window asks break the lock or not. But as I'm running a script, I would like to break from command-line tool. Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is locked because of a process keeping an handle on it, it can be as simple as killing that process, and relaunching the **[update](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccview_update.htm)** through the [CCRC Navigator View](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_tree_view.htm)

```
Refresh > Update from Repository
```

Regarding a ""`com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.copyarea.CopyAreaLockedException`" error message, the [IBM help page](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_break_lock.htm) mentions:

> The Copy Area Locked prompt appears when ClearCase encounters a `copyarea.lck` file after a user has attempted to rebase or deliver from a ClearCase Remote Client that resides on the same machine as the ClearCase native client.

So I suspect that your script need to find and remove that `copyarea.lck` file, in order to proceed.

But I would also recommend to check why (or if) there is a pending rebase or deliver in progress.
It would be best if that "rebase or deliver" was fully completed *before* your script runs.

The [OP jingxw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963079/jingxw) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974009/clearcase-view-is-locked-by-another-process-how-could-i-break-the-lock-from-ccr/19974819?noredirect=1#comment29850560_19974819):

> The progress is pending because of last progress is fail due to a timeout or manually quit. So the lock is expected.

Comment: seems that it doesn't locked by my previous process. I didn't find it in the result of "ps -a"

Comment: @jingxw I have edited my answer to address your specific error message.

Comment: This is exactly the solution for the question. Thanks a lot! @VonC

Comment: BTW, the progress is pending because of last progress is fail due to a timeout or manually quit. So the lock is expected

Comment: @jingxw Ok. I have added your conclusion to the answer for more visibility.