# ClearCase copy area write operation already in progress

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I am using Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 and ClearTeam Explorer 8.0.1.

When performing a Merge Search with ClearTeam Explorer I get a list of files to merge. Sometimes when trying to autmatically merge I get the following error:

> CRMAP7009: CCRC command "checkout" failed: Error: "com.ibn.rational.clearcase.remote_core.copyarea.CopyAreaLockedException: A copy area write operation is already in progress for copy area c:\cc\myvob. Retry the request once that operation completes.

After this error occurs eclipse often runs out of memory and crashes.

A clean reboot and restart of eclipse does not help. I have also tried `Refresh -> Update from Repository` which is suggested [in this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974009/clearcase-view-is-locked-by-another-process-how-could-i-break-the-lock-from-ccr#)

I can work around it by merging the files one by one but that gets tedious when merging 100+ files.

Comment: The error message is probably easier to read if you don't have to scroll.

Comment: @BSMP I agree but someone edited it.

Comment: Just to clarify, Is this issue happening using the CTE plugin? And if so, if you use the "full" CTE client, does the issue also occur? Are you the only person experiencing the issue? If so, is it because you're the one responsible for performing these large merges?

Comment: I will check on my next large merge and try to use the full CTE client.